# Reading in from a CSV data file, erroring out when trying to pull in only what I need

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to pull two columns of data from a CSV file and dump the rest.

The errors I am receiving are:

C2296: '>>': illegal, left operand has type 'std::basic_istream> &(__thiscall std::basic_istream>::* )(_Elem *,std::streamsize)'

C3867: 'std::basic_istream>::read': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

The data is formatted as such:

1928,44.50%,.......

I want the 1928 assigned into data.year, and the 44.50% assigned into data.yield, but not including the percent sign.

```
bool ReadData(MyData &data)
{
//Variable for reading data into file stream
ifstream inFile;
string trash;
char junk;

cout << "\nReading file . . .";

//Open data file
inFile.open("Data.csv");

//Read the first 18 lines, and throw it away
for (int i = 0; i < 18; ++i)
{
    getline(inFile, trash);
}

//Read the necessary data into the arrays
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
     //===============================================================
     //This line is throwing 2 errors
     //Goal: read first column of a simple integer into data.year, discard the comma, then read the second column of a double into data.yield, discard the percentage sign. infile.ignore(); to clear cin stream, getline(inFile, trash) to discard remainder of the lines.

    inFile.read >> data.year[i] >> junk >> data.yield[i] >> junk >> trash >> endl;

     //===============================================================
    inFile.ignore();
    getline(inFile, trash);
}

//Return false if file could not be opened
if (!inFile)
{
    cout << "\n\nTechnical error! The file could not be read.";
    return false;
}
else
{
    cout << "\n\nFile opened successfully!";
    return true;
}
inFile.close();
}

struct MyData
{
int year[SIZE];
int yield[SIZE];
double minYield;
double maxYield;
double avgYield;
};
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first problem is reading a file line by line constant number of times, however you never know the size of the file. So, you should add another check to your `for loop`. The second problem is that you say the yield is an `int` but it is a `double` in the file. The third problem is reading formatted data is not something like you did. The following piece of code can work for you, or you can play a bit with the code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE && std::getline(infile, line); ++i) {  
    std::stringstream linestream(line);
    std::string  year, yield;

    getline(linestream,year,',');
    getline(linestream,yield,',');

    yield.erase(std::remove(yield.begin(), yield.end(), '%'), yield.end()); // remove %

    myData.year[i] = std::stoi( year );  // string to int
    myData.yield[i] = std::stod( year ); // string to double

  }
```

**PS:** Don't forget to include `sstream` library.

Answer (score 0):

```
inFile.read >> data.year[i] >> junk >> data.yield[i] >> junk >> trash >> endl;
```

`inFile.read` is a function and has no operator `>>`, that's why you get the error. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read

I'd suggest you try a different approach: Read the entire line and use a explode function to retrieve the individual elements. For example [Is there an equivalent in C++ of PHP's explode() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966957/is-there-an-equivalent-in-c-of-phps-explode-function#12967010)